# Display all selected items from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I am using [this codepen](https://codepen.io/TauseefJanjua/pen/JERpQW?q=display%20selections&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false) as a basis.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input").on("click", function() {
  $("#log").html($("input:checked").val() + "");
});
```

I have changed the radio buttons to checkboxes - but I would like to alter the js so that every selected item is then shown at the bottom of the list, rather than just the first.

The purpose is for a self awareness exercise - i.e. the user could select all statements which apply to them from a long list, and then they get an output that narrows it down to just the ones they've chosen. The form response doesn't need to be saved/submitted anywhere.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes

- If want to be able to select multiple radio buttons, then either keep their names different or use checkboxes.
- Maintain an attribute `wasChecked` to toggle the checked property.
- You need to iterate the checked boxes and then get their values.

**Demo**

```js
$("input").on("click", function(e) {
  var val = [];
  var wasChecked = $(this).attr( "wasChecked" ) == "true";
  if ( wasChecked )
  {
     $(this).prop( "checked", false );
  }
  else
  {
     $(this).prop( "checked", true );
  }
  $(this).attr( "wasChecked", $(this).prop( "checked") );
  $("input:checked").each( function(){
     val.push( $(this).val() );
  });
  $("#log").html( val.join( "," ));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit1" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit2" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit3" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you - such a quick reply! This works and I can understand the script behind it, very clear, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function(e) {
 if(e.currentTarget.checked){
  var div = document.createElement("p");
  div.id=e.target.value+"1";
   div.innerHTML=e.target.value;
  var tar=document.getElementById("log");
  tar.appendChild(div);
} else {
  var tag = document.getElementById(e.target.value+"1");
  tag.parentNode.removeChild(tag);

 }  
});
```

You can try this its working.
Now when you click orange displayed and unchecked removed.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of jQuery function like `.val()` are designed to operate on a single element, i.e., `$("input#first-name").val()`, and so only return the value for the first element matched if there are multiple matches.

you will probably need a loop to extract a value for each element. fortunately, jQuery provides a function to do this as well.

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {

    var html = "";
    $( "input:checked" ).each(function() {
         // "this" in this context is the jQuery element in this position in the list
         html += $(this).val() + "";
    }
    $( "#log" ).html(html);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have an array. So, maybe you need something like this?

```js
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  var selectedItems = $( "input:checked" );
  var results = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){
    if(i > 0) results += ", ";
    results += selectedItems[i].value;
  }
  $( "#log" ).html( results );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ":checkbox" ).on('change',function(){
    var li_id = 'li_'+$(this).attr('id');
  if(this.checked){
     $('#list').append("<li id="+li_id+">"+$(this).val()+"</li>") 
  }else{
     $('#'+li_id).remove();
  }
})
```

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
<label for="orange">orange</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
<label for="apple">apple</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
<label for="banana">banana</label>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
</form>

<ul id='list'>
</ul>
```

This is just a simple example to add and remove items from the list if they're checked or not. At least it gives you an idea on how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Plain** **JavaScript** solutions:

With one loop:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myForm"),
  checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"),
  checked = document.getElementById("checked"),
  res = new Array(checkboxes.length);

function checkChecked() {
  [].forEach.call(checkboxes, (checkbox, i) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
      checkbox.checked ? res[i] = checkbox.value : res[i] = "";
      checked.innerHTML = res.join(",").replace(/(^[,]+)|([,]+$)/g, "").replace(/(,){2,}/g, ",");
    })
  })
}

checkChecked();
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="peach" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">peach</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</form>
<div id="checked"></div>
```

With two loops:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myForm"),
  checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"),
  checked = document.getElementById("checked");

function getResult() {
  var res = "";
  [].forEach.call(checkboxes, checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked ? res += checkbox.value + "," : false
  })
  res = res.replace(/(,$)/, "");
  return res;
}

function checkChecked() {
  [].forEach.call(checkboxes, checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
      checked.innerHTML = getResult();
    })
  })
}

checkChecked();
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="peach" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">peach</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</form>
<div id="checked"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function add(element)
{
var fruits=document.getElementById("log").innerHTML;
var fruit=element.value;
if(fruits=="")
{
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = fruit.toString();
}
else
{
if(document.getElementById(element.id).checked == true)
{
 fruits= fruits+' '+fruit.toString();
}
else
{
 fruits = fruits.replace(element.value,'');
}
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=fruits;    
}    
}
```

```html
    <form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="orange"  id="orange" onclick="add(this);">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="apple" id="apple" onclick="add(this);">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="banana" id="banana" onclick="add(this);">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</form>
```